# How to verify the test set while training the model？

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to add the test set verification function to my original code while training the model. I called the method of calculating the precision during training and tried to input the test set into the model. But after I run the code that I wrote according to my own understanding, the running result shows that the validation accuracy is larger than the accuracy of the training set. I guess it might be that I mistakenly put the test set into the model for training in one part. This is the result of existing code:
epochs: 0
train acc: 0.09489036     validation acc： 0.125

epochs: 1
train acc: 0.14082506   validation acc:    0.140625

I tried a lot of methods, such as creating two placeholders to hold the test dataset and the tags. But I feel that there is not much chance to solve the problem.

```
self.sess = tf.Session()

 self.x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, self.img_size, 
                         self.img_size, 3], name="image")
 self.y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 100], name="classes")

 self._build_net(self.x)

 cross_entropy = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(self.y_, self.predict, 
                                     reduction=tf.losses.Reduction.MEAN)

 l2 = tf.add_n([tf.nn.l2_loss(var) for var in tf.trainable_variables()])

 self.loss = cross_entropy + l2 * 0.0001
 self.pred = tf.argmax(self.predict, axis=1)
 self.accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal(self.pred, tf.argmax(self.y_, 
                                 axis=1)), tf.float32))

 self.train_op = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(self.learning_rate, 
                                            momentum=.9).minimize(self.loss)

 #problem is here (same with self.accuracy)   
 self.val =  tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal(self.pred, tf.argmax(self.y_, 
                            axis=1)), tf.float32))

 define _build_net(self, batch_images):
          ...
        CNN model
          ...

 def learn(self, x_batch, y_batch):
       _, loss, accuracy = self.sess.run([self.train_op, self.loss, 
                                         self.accuracy],feed_dict={self.x: 
                                           x_batch, self.y_: y_batch})
        return loss, accuracy

 #problem is here
 def validation(self, x_test_batch, y_test_batch):
      validation = self.sess.run(self.val, feed_dict={self.x: x_test_batch, 
                                 self.y_: y_test_batch})
        return validation
```

I want to know why I was wrong and expect to get the normal test set output. Or any suggestions that can be verified in my code to validate the test set during the training process.
Thank you very much for any help

Comment: So, your problem is that the model performs better on the validation set than on the training set? This might happen for some reasons, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49205773/would-it-be-possible-that-test-result-is-better-than-validation-result for example

Answer (score 0):

I re-added the epoch training and found that the validation accuracy did not increase after more than 45 epoch. Then the output becomes correct. But the reason why the test set is better at the beginning is still unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can verify loss of train and test easier if you use a tensorflow keras library. For example: model.fit_generator(train_data, epochs=nb_epochs, steps_per_epoch=nb_train_steps, validation_data=(valid_data, valid_label) where model are created using tf.keras.models

Since you are building a model from scratch, you should use the same intuition from model.fit_generator parameters: "nb_epoch", "train_steps", "batch_size"

In order to verify the test set while training the model, for example, you define:

```
x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test = tf.placeholder()
batch = 100  
iteration = 100000  
no_epoch = int(iteration/(len(x_train)/batch))  
train_loader = zip(x_train, label)

count = 0 # count to number of epoch

for epoch in range(no_epoch):
        for (x, labels) in train_loader:
            ### your model ###
            y_pred = model(x)
            loss = error(y_pred, labels)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

            count += 1
        if count % 50 == 0: # for ex train for 50 epoch:
            ### validation here ###
        ### you can store training history loss after 400 , 500 epochs etc ###

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ### load data, prepare x_train_batch, y_train_batch, x_test_batch, y_test_batch###
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(feed_dict={x_train: x_train_batch, y_train: y_train_batch, x_test: x_test_batch, y_test: y_test_batch})
```

I use pseudo-code for the intuition of using iteration, batch, no_epoch to verify/validate test/valid set while training so don't try to run it. Actually, that was my code implementation from Pytorch, but the same intuition holds for Tensorflow.

About the difference of train accuracy and validation accuracy, there is possibility that the weight initialization at first when you haven't trained enough is better to predict test set than train set. After you train long enough, if the problem still occur, it may be underfitting (bias, variance error)

Hope this helps!